Compile the Device Tree .dts file when it contains C-code
Problem:
When comping the U-boot software, the user need to specify the DEVICE_TREE argument when running the make file.
make X_defconfig
make DEVICE_TREE=my_device_dtb_file CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf- all

Then the software will look for a my_device_dtb_file.dtb file inside u-boot/arch/arm/dts folder. If the file does not exist, the compiling halts with an error.
Expected solution:
The expected solution is to compile the .dts file into a .dtb file.
$ dtc -I dts -O dtb -o test.dtb test.dts

Where the test.dts looks like
/dts-v1/;

#include <dt-bindings/pinctrl/stm32-pinfunc.h>
#include "stm32mp151.dtsi"
#include "stm32mp15xa.dtsi"
#include "stm32mp15xxac-pinctrl.dtsi"
#include "stm32mp15-m4-srm.dtsi"

/* USER CODE BEGIN includes */
#include "stm32mp15-scmi.dtsi"
#include "stm32mp15-scmi-u-boot.dtsi"
#include <dt-bindings/gpio/gpio.h>
#include <dt-bindings/mfd/st,stpmic1.h>
/* USER CODE END includes */

/ {
    model = "STMicroelectronics custom STM32CubeMX board - openstlinux-6.1-yocto-mickledore-mpu-v24.06.26";
    compatible = "st,stm32mp151a-stm32-mx", "st,stm32mp151";

    memory@c0000000 {
        device_type = "memory";
        reg = <0xc0000000 0x20000000>;

        /* USER CODE BEGIN memory */
        /* USER CODE END memory */
    };
    
}; /*root*/

This will give you the error:
 Error: test.dts:3.1-9 syntax error 
 FATAL ERROR: Unable to parse input tree

That's because the #include files. They are C code lines. The Device Tree Compiler dtc cannot handle C code.
Question:
I have see many people compiling .dts files that have C codes embedded inside. But how can that be done if I only have the tools:

U-boot source code https://github.com/u-boot/u-boot
ARM GCC Compiler from https://developer.arm.com/downloads/-/gnu-rm
Device Tree Compiler from https://github.com/dgibson/dtc

Goal & Aim
Compile .dts into .dtb file.
